# Application form with wrong position

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Do you know why my application form, when in runtime mode, is out of position and look like wierd? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean for 'out of position' ?

Comment: The form is bigger in runtime if compared to the one in Visual Studio

Comment: Try setting the [`AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) of your form from "Font" to "**None**".

Comment: I tried and did not work...

Comment: try by setting form `AutoSize = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the display it appears that the content of the form has not been set to adjust to the form as it expands.  Hence it stays the exact same as the form gets bigger and smaller.

There are a variety of techniques for dealing with this in WinForms.  The simplest of which is to simply dock the main control to the form.  Docking means that as the outer item expands the inner item will stay "docked" to the side that is listed.  In this case you'd want to make sure that the `Dock` property of the main control had the value `DockStyle.Bottom | DockStyle.Right`

This tutorial has a lot more detail on this subject and would be worth reading

> http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/

Answer (score 0):

Use Anchor property to align your controls on form